# Is there any way to apply last column first output value value as an input in first column second data in dataframe calculated with other column data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with five column data value.

five columns are ['A','B','C','D','time']

Here my 'D' column is the output column and 'A'is my first column.

So I want to apply that what ever the values represent in 'D' column that value should be the next input in 'A'column and with time range one hour.

Every one hour one hour values are changed.

I wrote a code and values are displaying, but my last column output is not my first column second input.

Here I upload my coda and csv file.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

```js
data = pd.read_csv('data20.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['time', 'A','B','C','D'])
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    data.loc[i+1,'A'] = data.loc[i, 'D'] + data.loc[i, 'B'] - data.loc[i, 'C']
```

In my csv file I colour the rows . Then the same color is representing in both columns mean in both columns same values are representing.

[image]

In my csv first row in A column 63 is represented and my output is 63 in D column. D column is my desired outputs. then in second row in A column its represented as 0. but I want to apply previous output value(63) into second row as A column input. Then that value will calculate by column B and reduce by C column then my desired output value is 60 represent in D column. So like this  process will continue.
So in A column 0 values replace by previous output value in D column.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you want, so where are you seeing incorrect values? in file? have you saved the file with updated dataframe?

Comment: checked is as well and your code works. the desired output would probaby be helpful.

Comment: @Sach Yes I saved it in dataframe. But still according to my output my third input is not display as 104. it is displaying as 62. So that is the problem.

Comment: @ZanshinBut still according to my output my third input is not display as 104. it is displaying as 62. So that is the problem. Some other input values are also not corrected properly

Comment: as per logic this is correct, your third row value of column A will be 62, forth will be 104.

Comment: please provide the desired output, not the actual one. this way we might see what the problem is.

Comment: @Sach But I want to put what ever the 'D' column value is there then it should be represent in glucose value with time range. Here I want to do this continuously in every hour.

Comment: @Zanshin I edit my question back.

Comment: @awa, I guess this not the desired output, is it? please show the exact output you would want to see in the end.

Comment: @Zanshin in the end I want to see that in next time means t+delata t (delat t =1hour) what will be the next output value. according to the previous values.assume that 6:00:00  A column value should be previous value of D column with other column calculation I want to find the output value at 7:00:00 a.m

Comment: last time I'll ask, please provide an example of the desired output. your explanations are not helping (me at least)

Comment: @Zanshin I changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to fill column 'A' with the value from 'D': `df['A'] = df['D'].shift(1)`.

But still, don't know why your own code is wrong.

Comment: I need to write this code continuously run in every hour . So how can I put that time range to my code. Do you have any idea about this matter?